# Ghost.Py keep windown shown

Tags: python, ghost.py

I currently using ghost.py and they have a function show() when I call it shows the website but instant close it. How to keep it open?

```
from ghost import Ghost
import PySide

ghost = Ghost()

with ghost.start() as session:
    page, resources = session.open("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login")
    session.set_field_value("input[name=username]", "joe")
    session.set_field_value("input[name=password]", "test")
    session.show()
    session.evaluate("alert('test')")
```

Answer (score 0):

The session preview will remain open until `session` exits - by leaving the session context `session.exit()` is implicitly called. To keep this open you need to either not exit the session context, or not use a session context.

The former can be achieved as so:

```
from ghost import Ghost
import PySide

ghost = Ghost()

with ghost.start() as session:
    page, resources = session.open("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login")
    session.set_field_value("input[name=username]", "joe")
    session.set_field_value("input[name=password]", "test")
    session.show()
    session.evaluate("alert('test')")

    # other python code
```

The latter can be achieved as so:

```
from ghost import Ghost
import PySide

ghost = Ghost()

session = ghost.start()
page, resources = session.open("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login")
session.set_field_value("input[name=username]", "joe")
session.set_field_value("input[name=password]", "test")
session.show()
session.evaluate("alert('test')")

# other python code
```

The session will however inevitable exit when the python process ends. Also worth noting is that some operations will return as soon as the initial http request has completed. If you wish to wait until other resources have loaded you may need to call `session.wait_for_page_loaded()`. I have also found that some form submissions require a call to `session.sleep()` to behave as expected.